# Value passed to servlet is coming as null in extjs4.2.2 - java servlet

Tags: java, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am new using ExtJS. I have created a login form, on Submit the parameter values should be passed to Servlet. Even the servlet is getting called, the value passing is null. Attaching the code snippet below, please help me in debugging the error.

login.js

```
Ext.application({
name: 'test-application',
launch: function() {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var login_details = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame: true,
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        padding: 10,
        layout: 'anchor',
        fieldDefaults: {
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 50
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%'
        },
        items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Login',
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                layout: 'anchor',
                defaults: {
                    anchor: '100%'
                },
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        columnWidth: 1,
                        layout: 'anchor',
                        items: [{
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                labelAlign: 'top',
                                fieldLabel: 'Username',
                                name: 'username',
                                id: 'username',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                padding: '0 0 10 0',
                                anchor: '60%'
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                labelAlign: 'top',
                                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                                inputType: 'password',
                                name: 'password',
                                id:'password',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                padding: '0 0 10 0',
                                anchor: '60%'
                            }]
                    }]
            }],
        buttons: [{
                text: 'Login',
                handler: function()
                {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: '/TestSystem/LoginServlet',
                        method: 'POST'
                    });
                    var formData = this.up('form').getForm();
                    formData.submit();
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Reset Form',
                handler: function() {
                    this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                }
            }]
    });

    var login_panel = new Ext.Panel({
        region: 'center',
        align: 'stretch',
        title: 'Test Automation',
        items: [login_details]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
                layout: 'border',
                defaults: {
                    collapsible: false,
                    collapsed: false,
                    split: false,
                    bodyStyle: 'padding:2px'
                },
                items: [{
                        region: 'north',
                        height: 150,
                        minSize: 75,
                        maxSize: 250,
                        cmargins: '0 0 0 0',
                        border: false
                    }, {
                        region: 'west',
                        width: 450,
                        minSize: 100,
                        maxSize: 250,
                        border: false
                    }, {
                        region: 'center',
                        align: 'stretch',
                        border: false,
                        layout: {
                            type: 'fit',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        },
                        items: [login_panel]
                    },
                    {
                        region: 'east',
                        width: 450,
                        minSize: 100,
                        maxSize: 150,
                        bodyStyle: 'padding:0px',
                        border: false
                    },
                    {
                        region: 'south',
                        width: 225,
                        height: 300,
                        minSize: 100,
                        maxSize: 250,
                        bodyStyle: 'padding:0px',
                        border: false
                    }
                ]
            }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
}
});
```

LoginServlet.java

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

 /**
  * @author Bijoy
 */

 @WebServlet(description = "Servlet used to validate users", urlPatterns = { "/LoginServlet" })
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println("Username from UI : " + username);
    System.out.println("Password from UI : " + password);
    }
}
```

I am using extjs-4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't require ajax request to submit your form.

All you need is form.submit() with the url config.

> **submit( options )** : Ext.form.Basic CHAINABLE Shortcut to do a submit
>   action. This will use the AJAX submit action by default. If the
>   standardSubmit config is enabled it will use a standard form element
>   to submit, or if the api config is present it will use the
>   Ext.direct.Direct submit action.

```
   var formData = this.up('form').getForm();
    formData .submit({
        clientValidation: true,
        url: '/TestSystem/LoginServlet',
        success: function(form, action) {
           Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
        },
        failure: function(form, action) {
            switch (action.failureType) {
                case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                    break;
                case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                    break;
                case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
           }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you handler with below code

```
{
            text: 'Login',
            handler: function()
            {
                var formData = this.up('form').getForm();
                formData.submit({
                       url: '/TestSystem/LoginServlet',
                       method: 'POST',
                       success: function(form,action){
                         // your success code once servelt returns response
                       },
                       failure: function(form,action){
                       }

                });
            }
```

submit it self will do ajax request.